A power series that is zero on an interval not containing zero must have zero coefficients
I want to show that if $g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^j$ is a power series converging on an interval $(a,b)$ not containing zero, and further $g(x) = 0$ on that interval, then $a_j=0$ for each $j$. Obviously if the interval contains zero we can just differentiate term-by-term to get what we want. I know this can be proven using complex analysis as mentioned HERE, but I was hoping for a proof that only uses elementary ideas from real analysis. Can anyone help with that?

You can just shift the power series to be in terms of $x - \frac{a + b}{2}$ and then take derivatives.

If it converges on $(a,b)$, then it converges on $(-r,r)$, where $r = \max{|a|,|b|}$

I thought about that but this was not too obvious to me. If we write $\sum_j^\infty a_j x^j = \sum_j b_j (x-(a+b/2))^j$, we know the $b_j's$ are zero, but it is not so obvious why this implies the $a_j's$ are zero. Doing so as far as I could see would amount to computing what the $a_j's$ are in terms of the $b_j$'s, but equating terms there seems to amount to assuming that when $\sum a_j x^j = \sum c_j x^j$, then $a_j=c_j$, which assumes the result.

@LostStatistician18 You can use the binomial theorem to choose specific $b_j$ that are explicitly in terms of $a_j$. Then all $b_j$ being zero will amount to a system of linear equations on $a_j$, whose only solution is all $a_j$ being zero.

@MPW, perhaps that works, but in this case we would not know that $g(x) = 0$ on $(-r,r)$, although perhaps we could derive this fact using Taylor's theorem or something to that effect.

@DavidGao I like the idea, but won't the linear system be infinite? I.e. if we write (with $c=(a+b)/2$) $\sum_j a_j (x - c + c)^j  = \sum_j b_j (x-c)^j$, we have $b_0 = \sum_j a_j c^j$, and similar such equations. I could not see why $a_j = 0$ is the clear solution to this.

@LostStatistician18 You’re right. It is slightly more complicated than I imagined. But this still works, as you can write $a_j$ in terms of $b_j$ in reverse as well. I’ll write a full answer giving the details.

@DavidGao Wonderful thank you David! Appreciate your insight on it!

I’m more or less ignoring the issue of convergence below, but these can all be justified using the fact that the power series converges within $(a, b)$.
Let $c = \frac{a + b}{2}$. Then,
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j &= \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j[(x-c)+c]^j\\
&= \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^j a_j \begin{pmatrix} j \\ k \end{pmatrix} c^{j-k}(x-c)^k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\sum_{j=k}^\infty a_jc^{j-k} \begin{pmatrix} j \\ k \end{pmatrix})(x-c)^k
\end{split}$$
Thus, if we let,
$$b_k = \sum_{j=k}^\infty a_jc^{j-k} \begin{pmatrix} j \\ k \end{pmatrix}$$
Then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty a_jx^j = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k(x-c)^k$. Since the power series evaluates to $0$ on an interval containing $c$, taking derivatives yields $b_k = 0$ for all $k$.
Now, we claim that,
$$a_j = \sum_{k=j}^\infty (-1)^{k-j}b_kc^{k-j}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ j \end{pmatrix}$$
Indeed,
$$\begin{split}
\sum_{k=j}^\infty (-1)^{k-j}b_kc^{k-j}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ j \end{pmatrix} &= \sum_{k=j}^\infty \sum_{l=k}^\infty (-1)^{k-j}a_lc^{l-k} \begin{pmatrix} l \\ k \end{pmatrix} c^{k-j}\begin{pmatrix} k \\ j \end{pmatrix}\\
&= \sum_{l=j}^\infty (\sum_{k=j}^l (-1)^{k-j}\frac{l!}{k!(l-k)!} \cdot \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!})c^{l-j}a_l\\
&= \sum_{l=j}^\infty (\sum_{k’=0}^{l-j} \frac{(l-j)!}{k’!(l-j-k’)!}(-1)^{k’})\frac{l!}{j!(l-j)!}c^{l-j}a_l\\
&= \sum_{l=j}^\infty (\sum_{k’=0}^{l-j} \begin{pmatrix} l-j \\ k’ \end{pmatrix} (-1)^{k’}) \begin{pmatrix} l \\ j \end{pmatrix} c^{l-j}a_l\\
&= \sum_{l=j}^\infty (1-1)^{l-j} \begin{pmatrix} l \\ j \end{pmatrix} c^{l-j}a_l\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} j \\ j \end{pmatrix} c^{j-j}a_j\\
&= a_j
\end{split}$$
Thus, as $b_k = 0$ for all $k$, we have $a_j = 0$ for all $j$.

Awesome thanks!
